# Using OR operator between group of columns in Grails criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a code that queries database using Grails criteria from groovy code. 
    Below is only part of test code that adds where clause/condition to the criteria.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : searchMap.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    String city = entry.getValue();
    eq("user.name", name)
    eq("user.city", city)
}
```

I want the resulting `WHERE` clause to look like,

```
    WHERE ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?) 
    OR ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?)
    OR ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?)
    .......
```

But my code always generates `WHERE` clause in the format,

```
WHERE ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?) 
    AND ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?)
    AND ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?)
    .......
```

Basically I want `OR` instead of `AND` between the name, city column groups.
    I tried solutions like,

```
    or {
        eq("user.name", name)
        eq("user.city", city)
    }

    or {
        and {
            eq("user.name", name)
            eq("user.city", city)
        }
    }
```

But nothing replaces `AND` with `OR`.
How can I achieve that.

**EDIT**

With,

```
or {
        eq("user.name", name)
        eq("user.city", city)
    }
```

the `WHERE` clause is generated as,

```
WHERE ( user.name = ? and user.city = ?) 
    AND ( user.name = ? OR user.city = ?)
    AND ( user.name = ? OR user.city = ?)
    .......
```

which is exacly opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be a solution for you. You have to mention `and` block explicitly.

```
def xx = Risk.createCriteria().list{
        or{
            and{
                eq 'isAccpeted', true
                eq 'isValid', true
            }
            and{
                eq 'investigationStarted', false
                eq 'isValid', true
            }
        }
    }
```

output

```
where ((this_.is_accpeted=? and this_.is_valid=?) or (this_.investigation_started=? and this_.is_valid=?))
```

As your code

```
or {
  and {
        eq("user.name", name)
        eq("user.city", city)
    }
  and {
        eq("user.name", name)
        eq("user.city", city)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group criteria in a logical OR using an or { } block

Your code could look like this:

```
For(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : searchMap.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    String city = entry.getValue();

    or {
        eq("user.name", name)
        eq("user.city", city)
    }
}
```

You can read about it in http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#criteria In the section 7.5.1. Conjunctions and Disjunctions you will find a couple of examples

When you have to deal with these scenarios I recommend to you to enable the sql loggin, if you use grails 3 in this [article](http://sergiodelamo.es/log-sql-grails-3-app/) explain it clearly the process, if instead you are using grails 2 check this [post](http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2013/08/20/grails-hibernate-logging)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you look at my question I have already tried using 'or' operator the way you suggested. But i am not getting expected output. I have edited the post to include output I am getting with your suggested code.

Comment: Could you share the Groovy builder you are using to build the Criteria